# Collisions when adding an address entry to the new table

Tags: bitcoin-core, peers, p2p, eclipse-attack

What does the bitcoin protocol do to handle collisions when adding addresses to the new table?

Comment: What addresses and what new table?

Comment: The addresses that are in the addr message are placed into the new table of bitcoin core.

Comment: Surely addr entries can't collide because there is no expectation that each peer has no peers in common. If two peers report a common addr entry wouldn't you just keep the common value in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of a collision of addrs in the new table, the existing address will normally stay (and nothing changes) - unless

- the existing entry is already present somewhere else in the new table (an address can be in up to 8 different buckets/positions at the same time), or
- if the existing entry is of bad quality ("terrible")

In these two cases the existing entry will be replaced by the new one.
There are several criteria by which a node can be terrible, roughly:

- if its timestamp is too far in the future or too far in the past from the current time.
- if we unsuccessfully tried to connect to it too often in the past

See [Addrman::IsTerrible()](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/aa6fb37accc6445855c81b6b236e574586df9c28/src/addrman.cpp#L67) for details / exact limits.
It may also be worth to mention that the behavior in case of collisions in the tried table is very different from this ("test before evict").